# activity behavior

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I have an app that calls at certain point an external `activity` (say maps) and supposedly when the external activity ends, another internal activity.
Basically the code calls the `startActivity` for the map and just after that, the `startActivity` for another view.
On Marshmallow the behavior is wrong, meaning that basically the latest startActivity win, showing the another view and not the map.
The map is called but never shows up.  If I comment out the second startActivity the map come up as expected.

There is some event I can override to determine when the external app (maps for example) is closed ?
And why on older version of Android it works ?
i.e. calling the two `startActivities` one after the other cause the first activity (the external one) to run and when is closed, the other `startActivity` takes places.
There is some extra parameter should be enabled for Marshmallow to have such behavior ?

Thanks for any hint/suggestion

Comment: The behaviour you expect does looks wrong, cause the second startActivity should be on top of the first, and when it finish it goes back to the first launched.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the case don't use `startActivities`. Start your first activity and `onCreate` of it start the map activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

**1)** Like mentioned above, first start your activity, and from that the map activity

**2)** You could start map activity using `startActivityForResult`, then **override** `onActivityResult`, and call your activity from that method.
See [Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I just inverted the calls leaving the call for the map "after" the call for the other activity and everything just works fine.
The question at this point is to understand why on the no Marshmallow devices it was working correctly.

Comment: It's strange, maybe you could add `Log`'s to the lifecycle callbacks(`onPause`, `onResume`, etc.) to get a more understanding of your `activity`'s lifecycle